# How to delete the space near the arrow in chemfig package?

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I have a problem with alignment of two chemical reactions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{flushleft}
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
A\arrow{->}B\arrow{->}
\schemestop
\bigskip

\schemestart
\arrow{->}C\arrow{->}D
\schemestop
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

How I can delete the space at the begin of the second line? Space between green and red markers?

[image]

Comment: First guess for an idea: shift the arrow using the optional argument which is meant for styling compounds

Comment: If I move the arrow, I don't move the reaction, is not it? I think there is way way to reduce/delete the space fields around or at the left of the arrow in the \arrow settings. But I don't find it.

Comment: Do you only want both lines aligned or do you also need both lines flush left with the margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the line left by adding some negative horizontal space before the scheme.  First you have to tell LaTeX to get out of vertical mode, using for example `\leavemode`.  In your case you then want to backup the empty node and the arrow offset, so you need `\hspace{\dimexpr-1em-4pt}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{flushleft}
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
A\arrow{->}B\arrow{->}
\schemestop
\bigskip

\leavevmode\hspace{\dimexpr-1em-4pt}
\schemestart
\arrow{->}C\arrow{->}D
\schemestop
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

The function of `\leavevmode` is to start a new paragraph if necessary.  If we are not in paragraph mode, any following horizontal spacing command will have no effect.

The expression `\dimexpr-1em-4pt` calculates a length from the two given quantities.  `1em` is a font related dimension, nominally the width of a letter `m` in the current font, and corresponds to the default arrow offset (according to the `chemfig` code, not its documentation).  The `4pt` comes from the empty node and seems to be built in to the `chemfig` code.

Comment: Many thanks. It really works. And please tell us how it works. I do not quite understand what is vmode and what is {\dimexpr-1em-4pt}? And -1em and -4pt shift the line left.

Comment: \leavevmode deletes the matgin of that line, doesn't it? Or not?

Comment: @EvgenyChem I have added some extra explanation to the question.  `\leavevmode` does not delete the margin, you still get the normal indent.

Answer (score 2):

In the following, I have just changed the margin of the page for this single line. Not really pretty, I fear, but if you need it just once, it might be ok:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist % credits to Vivi
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\schemedebug{true}
    \schemestart
        A\arrow{->}B\arrow{->}
    \schemestop
    \medskip
    \begin{changemargin}{-0.38cm}{0cm}
    \schemestart
        \arrow{->}C\arrow{->}D
    \schemestop
    \end{changemargin}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would printing c1 be a problem? It is only debugging information and invisible in the real case.

Comment: Wow! Unexpected approach . It looks at how you move an entire city to be your home became the center. It might be ok at once. But is there other way to delete that space. I really need shift whole the second line. And the printing of debuggin iformation is no problem:
\schemedebug{false}